# Troubleshooting Spark cluster shutdown

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, spark-streaming, amazon-emr

I'm new to Spark & AWS. We have a shutdown procedure for our Spark clusters. However, it's not gracefully shutting down. It gets stuck for some reason. Right now, we're using Splunk to log our shutdown procedure, however, Splunk has a 4 hour delay so this logging isn't helpful. Are there alternatives to easily trouble shoot this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using AWS EMR?

Comment: @Marcin yes I am!

Comment: EMR has logs on its own. Did you check them? Or you can ssh to the master node and investigate from inside.

Comment: @Marcin which log in the master node may let me know why it's having trouble failing? What I'm trying to do is having the cluster gracefully failover to the new cluster. What I notice is if I delete all the SQS queues and Kill Application for the existing Spark cluster, the new cluster will perform fine. If I don't do this, the graceful failover doesn't happen reliably. So wonder if the master node logs would help in this situation.